# Is it correct to say that p-values for Pearson's r decrease with increasing sample size because bias decreases with increased sample size?

Tags: correlation, p-value

I realise there are other reasons why p-values will decrease with increased sample size, but I am wondering if this reason is valid at all.

Comment: Which bias are you referring to?

Comment: If an estimator is biased, increasing the sample size will not necessarily make it any less biased. It depends on what kind of bias there is.

Comment: Empirical (sample) $r$ is biased. Population _estimate_ ("adjusted") is $|\rho|=\sqrt{1-(1-r^2)(n-1)/(n-2)}$, therefore the sample bias diminishes as $n$ grows.

Comment: @Glen_b The comment by ttnphns describes the sample bias I had intended to refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think people may be answering or commenting on a question you didn't intend.

@ttnphns is correct (as usual) that the bias does decrease with increasing sample size. But this decrease is pretty small. $\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n-2}}$ is small. If n goes from 10 to 100, this goes from $\sqrt{.9}$ to $\sqrt{.99}$ or from 0.949 to 0.995. If n is larger, the decrease is even smaller.

It is also true that the p value need not go down, as @Deathkill14 points out.

However, *in general* the reason the p value goes down with increasing sample size (given the same correlation) is not because of decreasing bias but because of increasing precision. A simple random sample of a population gives an estimate that is nearly unbiased, and that "nearly" because unimportant for reasonable n. But it gets more precise much more quickly. An approximation to the standard error of the correlation is given by

$SE[r] = \frac{(1-\rho^2)^2}{\sqrt{n-1}}$

so, for $\rho^2$ = .5 when n goes from 10 to 100 (as above) this goes from 0.08 to 0.025 and this decrease continues for increasing n.

Comment: Although in general the reason the p-value goes down with a larger sample size isn't decreasing bias, does decreasing bias contribute at all to the p-value going down?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't see how to separate it out, in general.

Answer (score 0):

The p-values need not decreases as sample size increases, but if there is a correlation that differs from your null value, then the p-values will tend to decrease. First, say that the null hypothesis, $H_0: r= 0$. 
Suppose you had two variables, $\pmb x_1$ and $\pmb x_2$, for which you would like to know if the correlation is significant.

As a first toy example, consider the case where $\pmb x_1$ and $\pmb x_2$ are independent, standard normal variables.

> library(Hmisc)
>
> n = c(20,50,100, 500, 1000, 10000)
>
> storeCorr <- rep(NA, 6)
>
> storePval <-  rep(NA,6)
>
> set.seed(123)
>
> X1 <- rnorm(n[6])
>
> set.seed(125)
>
> X2 <- rnorm(n[6])
>
> for (i in 1:6){
>
> x1 <- X1[1:n[i]]
>
> x2 <- X2[1:n[i]]
>
> storeCorr[i] <- cor(x1,x2)
>
> pval <- rcorr(x1,x2)
>
> storePval[i] <- pval$P[2] }
>
> storeCorr
>   [1] -2.049893e-01 -1.190268e-01 -6.825500e-02  2.582957e-02  4.984328e-02 -5.708832e-05
>
> storePval
>   [1] 0.3859574 0.4103422 0.4998307 0.5644682 0.1152124 0.995445619

As you can see, even as the sample size grows larger and larger the p-value does not necessarily get smaller since the the null hypothesis is true.

Now run the same code again, but create some correlation between X1 and X2. This will produce results more in line with your expectation. To do this replace X2 with

> set.seed(125)
>
> X2 <- 0.1*X1+rnorm(n[6])

Run the loop from the first experiment

> storeCorr
>   [1] -0.11052361 -0.02957047  0.01781262  0.12003696  0.14685975  0.09896175
>
> storePval
>   [1] 6.427365e-01 8.384702e-01 8.603720e-01 7.207274e-03 3.107059e-06 0.000000e+00

What we see now is that as the sample size grows the p-value eventually gets smaller and smaller. It starts out insignificant, because there is not enough information to convincingly show correlation, but as the sample size grows enough information is obtained.

To sum up, the larger your sample size, the more information you have about the generating process behind your data. If there is correlation between two variables, then you are able to more precisely identify it when you have more information (bigger sample). If there is no correlation between those variables, you will not find it (beyond Type 1 error).

Some more examples of the role of sample size on the significance of correlation coefficients is [here](http://irthoughts.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/on-correlation-coefficients-and-sample-size/), though this is not an authoritative source.